# Square root symbol

Tags: notation, roots, radicals

Can I add a '2' into the square root symbol?

Eg.  $\sqrt{x}$ will become $\sqrt[2]{x}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. That question is off-topic here.

Comment: Yes, since $\sqrt[2]{x}=x^\frac{1}{2}=\sqrt{x}$. For the sake of simple notation, the $2$ is often omitted from the radical.